# Delphi - Indy TIdHttp.Get with large URL length

Tags: string, delphi, http, indy, idhttp

I'm trying to use the GET method from Indy 10 however, my URL's length is bigger than 255 chars.
And GET method only accepts "string" parameters.

```
body := httpCom.Get('..........wide string.........')
```

Delphi's compiler give me the error:

> "String literals may have at most 255 elements"

Is there any solution or different third-party component to solve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how can delphi 'string' literals be more than 255?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767899/how-can-delphi-string-literals-be-more-than-255)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That no problem of the string type but the IDE, you can write it like this e.g.

```
Const
   C_URL = 'A long text with 255 Characters ....to be contionued ...'
          +'more content....to be contionued ... '
          +'more more content....to be contionued ... '
          +'enough content';
begin
  IDHTTP1.Get(C_URL);
end;
```

or

```
  IDHTTP1.Get( 'A long text with 255 Characters ....to be contionued ...'
          +'more content....to be contionued ... '
          +'more more content....to be contionued ... '
          +'enough content');
```

Answer (score 3):

`TIdHTTP` does not impose any limit on URL length, let alone a 255 character limit.  However, an HTTP server might impose such a limit on its end, and if it does then the request should fail with an HTTP `414 Request-URI Too Long` error code, per [RFC 2616 Section 10.4.15](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.4.15):

> 10.4.15 414 Request-URI Too Long
>
> The server is refusing to service the request because the Request-URI
> is longer than the server is willing to interpret. This rare
> condition is only likely to occur when a client has improperly
> converted a POST request to a GET request with long query
> information, when the client has descended into a URI "black hole" of
> redirection (e.g., a redirected URI prefix that points to a suffix of
> itself), or when the server is under attack by a client attempting to
> exploit security holes present in some servers using fixed-length
> buffers for reading or manipulating the Request-URI.

Comment: I'm not getting a result error from server.  
Delphi's compiler give me the error:  
"String literals may have at most 255 elements".  
Code:  
body := httpCom.Get('..........wide string.........');

Comment: Though it doesn't answer your question, I think Remy posted this answer because when someone will Google e.g. [`TIdHTTP URL length`](http://www.google.com/?q=TIdHTTP%20URL%20length) then it will result to your question and this post describes URL length limits of `TIdHTTP` control and HTTP protocol itself. And that's fine I think.